# Post wrong value if form submit with javascript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have a table with different items and id's for each item.
There are an dropdown menu for every item to delete/edit/start it.
My problem is, that only the first item-id is passed to every of my $post['item_id'].

```
$(document).ready(function() {

$('.dropdown-opt li').click(function() {
        document.getElementById('opt').value = $(this).data('value');
        $('#options').submit();
});


$("#options").submit(function() {
    if (confirm('proceed?')){
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
});
});

 <!-- BEGIN items -->
  <tr>
    <td align="center">
      <form name="" action="" method="post" id="options">
      <input type="hidden" name="item_id" value="{items.ID}">
      <input type="hidden" name="action" id="opt" value="">

      <li class="dropdown-opt"> 
        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Optionen<span class="caret"></span></a>
        <ul id="selector" class="dropdown-opt" role="menu">
          <li data-value="edit"><a href="#">Edit</a></li>
          <li data-value="start"><a href="#">Start</a></li>
          <li data-value="delete"><a href="#">Delete</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      </form>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <!-- END items -->
```

My first ID is 116 at this time, if i click on "Edit" I got POST-ID 116 on every item. But why?
I have

```
 <input type="hidden" name="item_id" value="{items.ID}">
```

on every item so it can't never be the same ID.

EDIT:
After add id='item_id' to the input hidden and update the javascript it works now.

```
 <input type="hidden" name="item_id" id="item_id" value="{items.ID}">

 $('.dropdown-opt li').click(function() {
        document.getElementById('opt').value = $(this).data('value');
        document.getElementById('item_id').value = $(this).closest('tr').find('input[name=item_id]').val();
        $('#options').submit();
});
```

The only thing that don't work was this line

```
 $(this).closest('tr').find('input#opt').val($(this).data('value'));
```

In this Javascript function

```
 $('.dropdown-opt li').click(function() {
        document.getElementById('opt').value = $(this).closest('tr').find('input#opt').val($(this).data('value'));
        document.getElementById('item_id').value = $(this).closest('tr').find('input[name=item_id]').val();
        $('#options').submit();
});
```

But this don't bring any issue as far as i can see.
Thank you very very much TechBreak!!!

Comment: Why the answer is marked as unacceptable, please put your comments ?

Answer (score 1):

You need to find `closest` `tr` first of the `li` element and then set the value in the respective `input` with `id` as `opt` and also get the required item id

```
    $('.dropdown-opt li').click(function() {
            $(this).closest('tr').find('input#opt').val($(this).data('value'));
            alert($(this).closest('tr').find('input[name=item_id]').val());
            $('#options').submit();
    });
```

Check this working demo

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.dropdown-opt li').click(function() {
    $(this).closest('tr').find('input#opt').val($(this).data('value'));
    alert($(this).closest('tr').find('input[name=item_id]').val());
    
  });
  $("#options").submit(function() {
    if (confirm('proceed?')) {
      return true;
    } else {
      return
      false;
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<table>

  <!-- BEGIN items -->
  <tr>
    <td align="center">
      <form name="" action="" method="post" id="options">
        <input type="hidden" name="item_id" value="115">
        <input type="text" name="action" id="opt" value="">

        <li class="dropdown-opt">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Optionen<span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul id="selector" class="dropdown-opt" role="menu">
            <li data-value="edit"><a href="#">Edit</a>
            </li>
            <li data-value="start"><a href="#">Start</a>
            </li>
            <li data-value="delete"><a href="#">Delete</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </form>
    </td>
  </tr>
    <tr>
    <td align="center">
      <form name="" action="" method="post" id="options">
        <input type="hidden" name="item_id" value="116">
        <input type="text" name="action" id="opt" value="">

        <li class="dropdown-opt">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Optionen<span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul id="selector" class="dropdown-opt" role="menu">
            <li data-value="edit"><a href="#">Edit</a>
            </li>
            <li data-value="start"><a href="#">Start</a>
            </li>
            <li data-value="delete"><a href="#">Delete</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </form>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
<!-- END items -->
```